# How to extract a .jar file and create a 100% identical new one

Tags: java, jar, extract, minecraft

I was playing around with the minecraft version files when I read about modifying the `version.jar` file to modify your game. I began to try out stuff and got stuck almost immediately.

I work on a Mac using the Terminal app.

My issue is the following:
I start having the `version.jar` file into a `TEST` folder.

- First I run `cd path_to_folder/TEST`.
- Then I run: `jar -xf version.jar` witch seems to extract the file filling the folder with `.class` files, some other files and some folders including the folder `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`.

At this point I try to recreate the `version.jar` file.

- First I delete the original `version.jar` file which is still present in `TEST` using `rm version.jar`.
- I run `jar -cmf META-INF/MANIFEST.MF 1.12.2_mod.jar *`  witch creates a new `version.jar` file.

Now I try to run it but it does not work.
Analyzing the dimension of both files (before and after), I don't get the same size: the original is `10’180’113` bytes and the new one `10’195’006` bites.

How can I resolve my issue?

EDIT:

Before trying to use the terminal I used the native decompress tool of MacOS, then compressed it to zip and finally renamed the extention into `.jar`. Doesn't work.

Same result if I renamed first the `.jar` extention into `.zip`, decompressed, compressed and finally renamed the extention. Doesn't work.

I tried also to use ***Keka*** to compress and decompress zip files. Doesn't work.

I could try to inject files into the `version.jar` file, but I've had a hard time with the syntax of the command...

Comment: There is nothing in your story suggests the size difference is the actual cause. JAR files are zip files, so depending on how or in what order, there might be minor differences in size. You need to compare the actual contents of both JARs to see what the problem might be. As an aside, hacking files like this is not for beginners. You are more likely to find help in a forum dedicated to Minecraft.

Comment: **Rule 1** for experimenting with computers: _Always **backup** your files beforehand._  

Did you follow it? 
If yes, compare the files to determine the differences.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I already know that rule, I just waned to point out that  that I do not include `version.jar` into the new one. I backed it up somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello myself from the past!

To edit `.jar` files on a Mac without to extract and recreate you can do the following:

- extract the whole `version.jar` on a new separate folder.

```
cd path_to_folder/TEST
mkdir tmp
mv version.jar tmp/version.jar
jar -xf tmp/version.jar
```

- Inside the `tmp` folder you can select the files you want to edit and bring them outside inside `path_to_folder/TEST`.
- delete the `tmp` folder.
- Do the modifications you want into your freshly selected files.
- To insert your modifications inside `version.jar`.

```
cd path_to_folder/TEST
jar -uf version.jar freshly_selected_file
```

Now you can run your `version.jar` with your modifications.

Comment: p.s. I used this procedure to add custom recipes on `1.12.2.jar` working on MacOS.